# Workflow mail triggering issue

Tags: workflow

I have created List Workflows using sharepoint designer. As per the design or code, as soon as new item is created, mail should trigger to the enabled list. Workflow is succesfully running but mails are not triggering the list memebers.

Comment: E-Mails will be sent to only registered member or site. Have you make sure that all the E-Mail address are register in SharePoint for any users?

Answer (score 0):

The following may be the reasons why the email is not triggering from the workflow:

- Outgoing email settings have not been configured in Central Admin. If configured then make sure the SMTP configuration has been done properly.
- Make sure that the email address is correct and the user exists in the User Profile.

If you need to check whether outgoing email has been configured correctly or not, just add a "test alert" to your document library. This will help you to know whether email is working or not.